# rospy and Subscriber/Publisher garbage collection

Tags: ros, rospy, publisher

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Do I need to store a reference to rospy subscribers and publishers to avoid these objects to be garbage collected?

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):

        # option 1, without reference
        rospy.Subscriber("/some/topic1", SomeMessageType, self.some_topic1_callback)

        # option 2, with reference
        self.my_subscriber = rospy.Subscriber("/some/topic2", SomeMessageType, self.some_topic2_callback)
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/415196/rospy-and-subscriber/publisher-garbage-collection/) by [knxa](https://answers.ros.org/users/29756/knxa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 811 on 2023-05-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is not necessary to store a reference to a Subscriber (but you can!). It will keep working even after that the `__init__` has been completed (of course as long as an instance of `SomeClass` is defined and the node is running).

As for the Publisher, in general, yes you should store a reference to it. In this way, you can publish also from outside the function in which you have defined it.

I hope that this example can help you:

```
class SomeClass:
    def __init__(self):

        # Defined Subscriber without reference
        rospy.Subscriber("/some/topic1", SomeMessageType, self.some_topic1_callback)

        # Defined Publisher with reference
        self.my_pub = rospy.Publisher("/some/topic2", SomeMessageType, queue_size=1)


    def some_topic1_callback(self, msg):
        
        # Do something with your message
        new_msg = self.great_function_doing_stuff(msg)
        
        # Publish the result
        self.my_pub.publish(new_msg)
```

---

Originally posted by [bluegiraffe-sc](https://answers.ros.org/users/69377/bluegiraffe-sc/) with karma: 221 on 2023-05-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2